# How to define periodic function in Fortran?

Tags: function, fortran

How can you define a periodic function in Fortran?

For example, `f(x) = exp(-x**2)`, for **–10** < **x** < **10** with period **20**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine with using [`MODULO`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MODULO.html)

```
f = exp(-(MODULO(x-10,20.)-10.)**2)
```

`x-10` is used to shift the repeating interval to -10,10. Otherwise,`MODULO(x, 20.)` would be periodic on interval 0,20. Because `MODULO` retuns values [0,20), the final -10 shifts it to [-10,10)

I assumed that x is `real`. If it has a different kind or even different type, the other argument to `MODULO` must be of the same type (`20._wp, 20.d0, 20,...)` as needed. The final `-10.` may also have to be adjusted to a higher kind.

Comment: Why the argument of ```MODULO``` is ```x-10```?

Comment: @StephenWong You need to translate your variable, e.g. f(x=15) should be calculated by f(x=-5). It depends on how you define your periodic interval, e.g. for g(x)=... for x=0..20 you dont need that.